# Facebook Access Token change format

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

My Facebook application for Android has always returned an access token of the type:

```
app_id|session_key|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Unfortunately a few hours ago it returned this token:

```
AAACwFsGcSr4BAOGUTwfuZAWuUcwZC0rJ7noZCKMqhBI7ivDCsIGqduGIZCus5PRaS6KuREqxLmhfvZAZAkz5WCpFfANtUpYHgZD
```

It is not even as a `signed_request` is not of this format:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

has no point

My chat that uses X-FACEBOOK_PLATFORM authentication does not work anymore because I can not find `session_key`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is the new encrypted token format.  Not knowing how you were using the old token limits what I can tell you as to how to utilize the new token but this might help:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I had read that document.
Unfortunately my encrypted access_token

AAACwFsGcSr4BAOGUTwfuZAWuUcwZC0rJ7noZCKMqhBI7ivDCsIGqduGIZCus5PRaS6KuREqxLmhfvZAZAkz5WCpFfANtUpYHgZD

does not contain the point of separation as described in the document:

vlXgu64BQGFSQrY0ZcJBZASMvYvTHu9GQ0YM9rjPSso
.
eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsIjAiOiJwYXlsb2FkIn0

The format does not seem to match.
I hope someone can help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

we should not code against the format of the access token.
even in the "unencrypted form", Facebook should have never documented its format.  It just by "luck" that you own way works.  It is not supported.

Comment: Thanks, but I still can not figure out how to use this type of token or encrypted access token old will transform to extract the session key

Comment: you should not try to do this... and it is not supported